# recordedAudioURL from udacity

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wRgh.png)I'm following a class on Udacity but I can't proceed because of a problem. I have the code `playSoundsVC.recordedAudioURL = recordedAudioURL` but it says `PlaySoundsVC` has no member of `recordedAudioURL`

[image: Myself]

There's an error but on the lesson this does not cause a problem.

[image: Udacity]

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Here're the codes of PalySoundsVC
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zkn9.png)

Comment: It says to you that it can not find a property called `recordedAudioURL` on your `PlaySoundsVC` so double check that you actually have a property called `recordedAudioURL` on that ViewController. And also...could you add the code from `PlaySoundsVC` to your question? That'd make it easier for us to help you :)

Comment: My PalySoundsVC does not have recordedAudioURL but I'm following the lesson from udacity and didn't see an recordedAudioURL statement on the videos. Could you let me know where and how to add it?

Comment: Btw I also uploaded the screenshot of my PlaySoundsVC codes